# noun pattern; fabrication, finishing, assembly

Tags: gerunds, lists, parallelism

The sentence goes like this:

> Structures classified in group f1 are occupied for the purpose of fabrication, finishing, manufacturing, packaging, assembly or processing of materials.

Here the question is

1. Can fabrication and assembly be re-written into fabricating and assembling?
2. If not, why?
   ­­

Answer (score 1):

I lean toward keeping the original in both cases.

Fabrication has to do with manufacturing, but "to fabricate" has another meaning -- to make something up, or to lie!

Assembly is a nice stand-alone word, whereas when you talk about assembling, the listener or reader is going to want to know what you are assembling (or putting together).